# lighttpd shows 404 not found when i enter a subdirectory

Tags: lighttpd

I have a server running lighttpd, so I could host a website on it.

But thing is that when I enter a sub directory such as "domain.com/example/" I get a "404 - Not Found".

Here is my [lighttpd configuration](http://pastebin.com/bHwdeQHX) if you want to take a look at it.

Any help would be greatly a appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding

`#directory listing
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
dir-listing.hide-dotfiles = "enable"
dir-listing.encoding = "utf-8"`

at the end of the configuration file ;)